# Validity of InAct study codes with PMP Exam Change coming

Tags: pmp

I have the study guides, books, and the online codes from InAct through my local PMI chapter.  Due to a myriad of reasons (and excuses) I wasn't able to schedule my PMP exam until after the 31 Aug change.  Generally I have done very well on online practice exams, but I want to make sure I keep my PMI hat on and proficiency in the exam taking.  Does anyone know if the online InAct codes will allow me to access updated study material?  I have not used those codes as of yet and been doing practice exam on other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you ask your local PMI Chapter (the same place where you got the codes)?

Comment: Yes, I did, and they just seemed unsure.  As a StackExchange participant on numerous sites here, I figured that getting a second opinion would be worthwhile.

Comment: Did you try asking InAct?

Comment: I didn't ask them (yet)  I figured that as a StackExchange site, if I had an answer, then other people like brightblades could also have that answer available to them.  It's all about communication.  :)

Comment: @Larian, hey I saw your FB update that you passed.  Any thoughts on this question then?